# Access array of posted html form variables with same name[]

Tags: html, arrays, delphi, forms, post

I am working on a web application written in delphi and am having trouble getting the values from an array of values. The form looks similar to this:

```
<form method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="keyword[]" value="1"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="keyword[]" value="2"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="keyword[]" value="3"/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

If this were a single input with a unique name, I could pull the data using this:

```
var cKeyword : String ;
cKeyword := Request.ContentFields.Values['keyword'] ;
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
var aKeywords : Array of String ;
aKeywords := Request.ContentFields.Values['keyword[]'] ;
```

In PHP you could just use `$aKeywords = $_POST['keyword']`, I'm hoping there's a way to do this in delphi.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: The square bracket notation is specific to php and has nothing to do with html or any other language that I am aware of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ContentFields` property is just an ordinary `TStrings` object, so its `Values` property always returns a `string`. When an HTML form has multiple successful controls with the same name, they're simply all returned, one after the next. That means the `TStrings` object will have multiple entries with the same `Names` value. You'll need to iterate over all the entries to find the ones with matching names.

Here's a function that might help.

```
function GetArrayFieldValues(ContentFields: TStrings; const FieldName: string): TStringDynArray;
var
  i: Integer;
  Values: TStrings;
begin
  Values := TStringList.Create;
  try
    for i := 0 to Pred(ContentFields.Count) do
      if ContentFields.Names[i] = FieldName then
        Values.Add(ContentFields.ValueFromIndex(i));
    Result := Values.ToStringArray;
  finally
    Values.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Call it like this:

```
aKeywords := GetArrayFieldValues(Request.ContentFields, 'keyword[]');
```